# Tomcat Server "Commons Daemon Service Manager" Command prompt

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have installed the latest tomcat 9.0.0.M10 server on my windows 10 laptop.
I have successfully configured the tomcat in Eclipse Luna IDE as well.

But I want to open the command prompt "Commons Daemon Service Manager" in my windows to run a jspapplication without using IDE.

How to go ahead with this situation.

Comment: First off all you must build your application in your IDE and then deploy it in Tomcat.

Comment: Through IDE I know how to do it. Also I have deployed the application in the tomcat9/webapps folder.

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli what next after deploying..?? I  opened the browser and typed http://localhost:8085 , enter.

Comment: I don't know your port. You must check that from server.xml. By default it may be localhost:8080/AppName

Comment: I will add as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Let's describe step by step.

1. Creating *.war file. Right click on your app, Export and select WAR File.
   [image]
2. Locate this `WAR File` in Apache Tomcat WebApps folder.
3. Start Apache Tomcat.

For running your app you must check Apache Tomcat default port. By Default it will 8080. For my example it will http://localhost:8080/TestApp. You can change default port what you want.

For checking default port you must find server.xml file under ApacheTomcat/conf/server.xml. Find uncommetted Connector tag.
By default it will look like following.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```